# What is the danger of going beyond the current limits of a wire carrying AC current

Tags: safety, fuses

If I am using 18 AWG wires with a current limit of 16 A, 
what are the potential hazards of going beyond 120V,AC and 16A,AC(rms)?

Comment: Even a current of 1A can start a fire. So, it depends of your application. Your question now is too broad to answer.

Comment: @Huisman I will edit to make it more specific.

Comment: I would not run 16A through 18AWG wire inside a building. Only if the wire was exposed to open air or convection flow and used high temperature insulation. Usually there is some type of building code applicable. Or other code for cars and boats and so-on. All the details matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you exceed the current rating, the most likely risk is that the wire overheats and starts a fire.

If you exceed the voltage rating, the most likely risk is that the insulation on the wire breaks down, allowing the wire to short to nearby objects (causing high currents that can cause a fire, or electrocuting users), or causing sparks that can cause a fire.